# Is this XML block valid or not?

Tags: xml, dtd

Is that my XML code valid or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE nahrung [
  <!ELEMENT nahrung      (obst|gemuese|sonstiges)+>
  <!ELEMENT obst    (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT gemuese    (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT sonstiges    (#PCDATA|beschreibung)*>
  <!ELEMENT beschreibung    EMPTY>
  <!ATTLIST beschreibung artikelname CDATA #REQUIRED
    preis CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<nahrung>
    <obst>Pflaume</obst>
    <gemuese>Kohl</gemuese>
    <sonstiges>Keks</sonstiges>
    <sonstiges><beschreibung preis="22.50"
         artikelname="banane"/></sonstiges>
    <gemuese>Gurke Preis: 22.50</gemuese>
</nahrung>
```

i have a `<!ELEMENT nahrung      (obst|gemuese|sonstiges)+>` that means **obst** OR **gemuse** OR **sonstiges** only one time in xml appear and not all of them  altogher.Did I understand correctly?

Comment: If i put that into a new xml file within eclipse, it doesn't tell me any errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML looks like it should successfully validate against your DTD - but I don't think that your DTD matches what you are expecting.

Specifically, this line from your DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT nahrung      (obst|gemuese|sonstiges)+>
```

Means that I you must have 1 or more of the elements from that list.

If you only wanted to allow one child element, for example (either obst **OR** gemuse **OR** sonstiges), you could use this:

```
<!ELEMENT nahrung      (obst|gemuese|sonstiges)>
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
(obst|gemuese|sonstiges)+
```

means "any non-zero number of `obst`, `gemuese`, and `sontiges` elements, in any order."

Comment: That means that | does not mean OR ? and for example Obst could appear twice or gemuse once and sonstiges thrice? correct?

Comment: It does indeed mean "or", but "+" means "one or more of." So your complete sequence is any one of the three, followed optionally by any one of the three, followed optionally by any one of the three... etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `(obst|gemuese|sonstiges)+` means either one of those 1 or more times. Meaning this xml is valid.